# How to go back in history and remove a large binary file committed and pushed by accident in Git?

Tags: git, version-control, github

I did a `git pull --rebase` without realizing it ended up downloading a huge binary file which was not supposed to be pulled. I did a commit and pushed my work along with this huge binary file.

I need to go back in time, remove it, and replay all of my work on top of all the pushes from other developers, there are other pushes to the repo. I was working on a separate branch.

This is a serious problem, I keep screwing up with Git! Would like some good starting guide to Git.

Comment: Where did this huge binary file come from in the first place? You say you pulled it, does that mean someone else added it? You say you pushed it, does that mean you modified it locally and added it?

Comment: Please see my profile for various Git resources. In particular, I ***highly recommend*** the [**FREE online Pro Git book**](http://git-scm.com/book), particularly chapters 1-3 and 6-6.5. Also please learn how to `rebase` both interactively and non-interactively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at `git filter-branch`. This will get rid of the giant object from your local repo.

The other way to do it is to remove the addition of the giant file by using `git rebase -i HEAD~5` if your offending commit is 5 commits ago. Mark that commit with e for "edit". When you get there, unstage and delete the giant file, commit and `git rebase --continue`. Then do a force push `git push -f origin yourbranch` or simply `git push -f` if you have your branch tracked properly.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to revert your last commit and push it again

```
git revert HEAD
```

Comment: If the original poster wants to completely remove the binary file from history, then this won't do that, it will only remove it from future commits, but it will still exist in past commits. The only way to remove it from history is either with a hard `reset`, a `rebase`, or a `filter-branch`.